# Is there any way of getting multiple ranges of values in numpy array at once?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say we have a simple 1D ndarray. That is:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

I want to get the first 3 and the last 2 values, so that the output would be `[ 1  2  3  9 10]`.

I have already solved this by merging and concatenating the merged variables as follows :

```
b= a[:2]
c= a[-2:]
a=np.concatenate([b,c])
```

However I would like to know if there is a more direct way to achieve this using slices, such as `a[:2 and -2:]` for instance. As an alternative I already tried this :

```
a = a[np.r_[:2, -2:]]
```

but it not seems to be working. It returns me only the first 2 values that is `[1 2]` ..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `r_` requires explicit size information.  Practice using it alone. But under the covers it's a concatenate of `aranges`.  So you have to do a concatenate one way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

Slicing a numpy array needs to be continuous AFAIK. The `np.r_[-2:]` does not work because it does not know how big the array `a` is. You could do `np.r_[:2, len(a)-2:len(a)]`, but this will still copy the data since you are indexing with another array.

If you want to avoid copying data or doing any concatenation operation you could use `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`:

```
ds = a.dtype.itemsize
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(2,2), strides=(ds * 8, ds)).ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  2,  9, 10])
```

But since you want the first **3** and last **2** values the stride for accessing the elements will not be equal. This is a bit trickier, but I suppose you could do:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(2,3), strides=(ds * 8, ds)).ravel()[:-1]
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  2,  3,  9, 10])
```

Although, this is a potential dangerous operation because the last element is reading outside the allocated memory.

In afterthought, I cannot find out a way do this operation without copying the data somehow. The numpy `ravel` in the code snippets above is *forced to make a copy of the data*. If you can live with using the shapes `(2,2)` or `(2,3)` it might work in some cases, but you will only have *reading* permission to a strided view and this should be enforced by setting the keyword `writeable=False`.

Comment: You are right, I try to avoid copying data somehow! Thank you for your detailed answer, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to access the elements with a list of indices.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
b = a[[0,1,2,8,9]] # b should now be array([ 1,  2,  3,  9, 10])
```

Obviously, if your array is too long, you would not want to type out all the indices.
Thus, you could build the inner index list from for loops.
Something like that:

```
index_list = [i for i in range(3)] + [i for i in range(8, 10)]
b = a[index_list] # b should now be array([ 1,  2,  3,  9, 10])
```

Therefore, as long as you know where your desired elements are, you can access them individually.

Comment: But this doesn't save effort or time.  `b` is still a new array with its own data.

Comment: You 're right, nevertheless, ΄a = a[index_list]΄ is considered as the most appropriate solution yet as far as - memory management by avoiding copying the whole table - is concerned